# gdb SIGABRT and not SIGSEGV

Tags: c++

hee,

i am using gdb to exploit my program

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
if(argc < 2) {
    printf("You have vergotten to fill in a value\n");
    exit(0);
}

char buffer[10];
strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
printf("the value you supplie is ");
printf(buffer);
printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

in the vindeo tutorial he types in, in gdb "run AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
and there should becoming:

```
program received signal SIGSEGV, sementation fault.
0x41414141 in ?? ()
```

but i got SIGABRT

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: /root/Desktop/out terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7ffff7b59217]
/lib/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x0)[0x7ffff7b591e0]
/root/Desktop/out[0x400759]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7ffff7a78c4d]
/root/Desktop/out[0x400609]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 148883                                 /root/Desktop    /out
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:01 148883                             /root/Desktop    /out
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 148883                             /root/D
```

etc. and then SIGABRT

what is the reason i get SIGABRT and not SIGSEGV?

Comment: Maybe you run in some sort of managed environment that checks memory accesses for you?

Answer (score 6):

You compiler implements [*stack smashing protection*](http://www.research.ibm.com/trl/projects/security/ssp/). The runtime tells you about it. Try putting your buffer outside of the function - there you most likely to get a segmentation fault.

By the way, it's not the greatest idea to play with exploits under `root`.