# JVM 1.8 crashed with SIGABRT on centos

Tags: jvm, coredump

my java application crash with coredump

[image]

coredump say terminated with signal 6 but hs_err_pid file was different:

[image]

it makes me confused

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gdb SIGABRT and not SIGSEGV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074584/gdb-sigabrt-and-not-sigsegv)

Answer (score 3):

`SIGSEGV` is caught and handled by the JVM itself.

In response to `SEGSEGV` JVM writes `hs_err_pid.log` and then terminates process with [`abort()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/574c3b0cf3e5/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp#l1515) call to force core dump. `abort()` call results in [`SIGABRT`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/abort.3.html).